# How to create vertical and horizontal swipeable cards in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, design-patterns

I have created a simple app with swipecards (similar to tinder) where you scroll left and right on images of cars :) whether you like or dislike them. That all works fine using a library called Swipecards: https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards

Now, what I want to do next is make it so that when you scroll down the swipecards disappear and you see the description of the car and then you can scroll down one more time to see more images. Essentially how the other dating app, bumble works. You can then scroll back up to the swipecard view.

How would I achieve the scrolling up and down effect? Would I put my swipecards in a listitem of a listview and so there would be 3 listitems in my listview: 1 for the original image that you can swipe left and right, 1 for the description, and 1 for more image tiles.

Is a listview my best approach at achieving this effect? I tried searching for similar tutorials online but couldn't really find anything for the vertical scrolling.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need a recyclerview as that provides animations. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHqpR3yLNfk

Comment: @Tasos would I put a recyclerview inside my swipecards or would the recyclerview contain the swipecards? Scrolling up and down should only display the items for that particular swipecard.

Comment: The RecycleView can handle all sorts of animations, including custom ones so i presume thats all you need. Check on github for premade Recycler view animation libraries like this one to speed things up https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators

Comment: Hello, Did you get any solution? I need to implement same kind of functionality like bumble.. swipe images up and down with card swipe left or right direction.. Please help.. Thanks in advance 
Currently I am using https://github.com/aaronbond/SwipeDeck2 
But unable to scroll in vertical viewpager which is child item of swipable card.

Comment: @Mihir Shah did you found any solution for this? I also have to implement same as bumble swipes. As i can see that bumble is using view pager for image sliding towards top and bottom but how would i acheive swipe left and swipe right animation?

Comment: @AnilKumar, didn't find the exact solution. But I did by using viewpager as a child (vertical viewpager) and swipedeck2 library. use swipedeck as a parent and add viewpager to it's each child in adapter. And prevent card swipe if you found swipe is invertical direction in swipedeck library. Also pass your touchevent to the adapter from swipedeck library and use this touchevent for verticalviewpager. That's the only solution I found.

Comment: @Mihir Shah Thanks for your revert! I also found a solution by using a combination of doubleviewpager library and swipedeck2 library. By default i used the touch for vertical view pager and when motion is in horizontal direction then i transferred the touch to it's parent which is card swipe. It's working nice but i have noticed a little lag which is out of ignorance. Did you encounted any such issue with your implementation?

Comment: @AnilKumar  Can You Provide Code ?@Mihir Shah if you can Provide It please

Comment: can you please provide working code?